# Apache James not receiving email from external senders after SSL enabled

Tags: apache, email, ssl, smtp, james

Very new to James, so please bear with the question.

James 2.3.2.1, Ubuntu 14.04.
Configured as both POP3 and SMTP. SSL enabled and certificate store successfully connected.

The problem is this: once SSL is enabled, the SMTPS listen port is 465, and there is no longer a listener on the standard port 25 to receive email from external senders (e.g., from Gmail). Thus mail delivery sent to local accounts works when sent from other local accounts, but fails when sent from external servers.

Is it possible to configure James to listen both on the standard port 25 for external senders and on the secured port 465 for authenticated senders? If so, how is it done, and how do I make sure it doesn't become an open relay (i.e., only receives mail sent to local user accounts)? With the SSL configuration, I just set both authRequired and verifyIdentity to true, which ensures only authenticated users can send mail. With standard SMTP, I'm not sure:
a) how to configure it while also having the secured connection; and
b) how to avoid becoming an open relay.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't find a way to do this in James, but my goals were:
a) secured SMTP for authenticated (domain) user accounts;
b) regular SMTP for receiving email from external servers;
c) not becoming an open relay.

I achieved this by using the nifty OpenSMTPD server relaying to the secured James port. Took a while to get the configuration right on both servers, but the setup is working like a charm now.

Postfix looked too complicated to set up, and Sendmail does not support client-side SSL connections (to secured SMTP servers). OpenSMTPD is a lifesaver.